# Servicestack request no quotes in json body

Tags: json, angular, typescript, servicestack

Can someone tell me why do I see quotes in my request body in Fiddler and my servicestack request field has none?

```
POST http://10.255.1.180:8087/testvariables/new/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.255.1.180:8087
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 162
Origin: http://10.255.1.180:8087
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://10.255.1.180:8087/certFields
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6

{"Field":{"Id":67,"Name":"Brightness Reversion","Header":"Brightness Reversion.","Format":"#0.0","Uom":"%","Precision":0,"MapId":8083,"IsMappedToCustomer":false}}
```

Call from Typescript/Angular2

```
let body = JSON.stringify(certField);    
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' });

let requestoptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: this._certFieldsUrl + 'new/',
            headers: headers,
            body: '{"Field":'+body+'}'
        })
return this._http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
            .toPromise()
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json() as CertFieldSaveResponse;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

Request Class

```
public class CertFieldUpdateRequest : IReturn<TestVariableResponse>
    {
        public string Field { get; set; }

    }
```

POST Method

```
    public object Post(CertFieldUpdateRequest request)
    {
                log.Debug(request.Field);
       ....
    }
```

Inside the service, in the POST method, the value of the request.Field is:

```
    {Id:67,Name:Brightness Reversion,Header:Brightness Reversion.,Format:#0.0,Uom:%,Precision:0,MapId:8083,IsMappedToCustomer:false}
```

Comment: because one is raw output, and one is "cleaned up". JSON without quotes is **NOT** valid json.

Comment: change `.then(function (response) {` to `.then((response) => {` and see and tell.

Comment: like Marc says if the last json you show is what you post, it wont work. Try: `var body = { Field : Body }`. and then `JSON.stringify(body)`

Comment: @jbrabant has your problem been solved?

Comment: @joelharkes No it has not.  The last JSON you see is not what I POST.  It is what I see in debug watch inside the POST method of my servicestack service.

Comment: This happens because Field is a `string` thus it is not further deserialized. If you want it to deserialize make an class out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your body is actually a complete json object and not a string inside a json object. so either:

```
   let requestoptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        url: this._certFieldsUrl + 'new/',
        headers: headers,
        body: {Field : JSON.stringify(body)}
    })
```

Or make your code class have properties:

```
   public class CertFieldUpdateRequest : IReturn<TestVariableResponse>
   {
    public Field Field { get; set; }

   }

   public class Field
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        ///etc...
    }
```